# How can i update values stored in map to database after every 1 hour while synchronizing incoming requests on route which updates map continously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, data-synchronization

I am facing a problem to update the values stored in map to database because the map is updating continously due to incoming requests on the route and at the same time I want to update values in database periodically with the help of map. How to synchronize both the operations?

```
const url_count = new Map();

async function update_count(){
 
    // update value in mongodb 
    
}
app.get('/teeny/:code', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const url = await Link_URL.findOne({
            _id : req.params.code
        })
        if (url) {
          if(url_count.has(req.params.code)){
            const val = url_count.get(req.params.code);
            url_count.set(req.params.code,val+1);
            update_count();
          }
          else{
              url_count.set(req.params.code,1);
          }  
            return res.redirect(url.URL);
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json('No URL Found')
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.status(500).json('Server Error')
    }
})
cron.schedule('* * 1 * *', update_count);
```

Comment: You want to perform a batch insert?

Comment: Yes, i want to batch update all the values stored in map to database after every 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Later](http://bunkat.github.io/later/) for a simple solution... here you would be collecting all those values and then insert them at a specified time that you specified in later..

For something heavier, you could go for [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) or for [Rabbot](https://github.com/arobson/rabbot)

If you want to kill a lion, go for [Node-Celery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-celery)... but make sure to have python installed.

Basically, all you need is a queuing system to collect[in a queue] all those tasks that you want to save later...

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but there is a misunderstanding with the problem. I want to count all the same types of tasks(route hits) in 1 hour then i have to update it in database. If i use a queue i don't feel it would help me in any way to keep a count of same tasks(route hits).

Comment: A queue would.... every time a request hits, you add a new thing in a queue...

Then, you could either have a counter variable that updates on every hit. Many queues have events for tracking this... or you could count the objects in a queue after that hour.... which